# using config file for html pages without server code

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm beginning to develop an app on phonegap. Right now, in every page I have the reference

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://someServer/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

But if someServer changes to other server, i would have to refactor every reference everywhere. I want to put that in a config file and use it, but I don't know how to do it without server code...please help me with that or tell me if there is a way to handle that kind of things on phonegap.... thanks to all of you

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your import.js and each page will reference to this import.js.

Import.js will contain smth like:

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "http://someServer/js/myscript.js";

document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been already answered at the thread below.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/8Hca4Izo9Ss/Zuse0y7SZxQJ